# Hide TextBox in SSRS based on field value

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am creating a SSRS report and i would like to give some condition for textbox. based on the condition the textbox should be visible or hidden. When the field value is no, then the text box should hide.

I am inside the textbox properties and in Visibility (fx). I gave the condition as

```
   =IIf(Fields!IsStudent.Value = "No", True, False)
```

If the value is no, then my textbox => StudentDetails , should be hidden. If the value is YES, the testbox should be visible.
CAn someone help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Your expression in **Show or hide based on expression**

```
=IIf(Fields!IsStudent.Value = "No", True, False)
```

is right. If the field `Fields!IsStudent.Value` has the value `No` (string) your textbox should hide. Check if your textbox hides when you put in the following expression:

```
=IIF(1=1, True, False)
```

If this works your `Fields!IsStundent.Value` doesnt return `No`. And if your `IsStudent.Value` is not a field you have to reference it with `ReportItems!IsStudent.Value`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes I tried that expression
       =IIf(Fields!IsStudent.Value = "No", True, False)
the value of the student field is no, when i add this expression for hiding the text box, it is not hiding

Comment: Well then something with your field isnt right. It doesnt seem to have the value `No`.

Comment: The `IIf` is redundant. The return of `Fields!IsStudent.Value = "No"` is `True` so you are saying "If True = True Then True". `=Fields!IsStudent.Value = "No"` is sufficient.